# Getting Java to accept only one SSL certificate

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've got a java applet that loads some pre-installed native code extensions to display custom content in the browser.  Some of this content may include native code to be loaded by the JVM.  Obviously, this is a security concern. I'd like to enforce that all content comes only from authorized servers.

The path I've been following to accomplish this is to create a keystore that contains just one SSL certificate.  I set the keystore location and password and turned on debug output.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\keys\\keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");
```

I was under the impression that this would mean that the JVM would have access to only the one keystore file and consequently the one key inside it.  In fact, the SSL debug info lists something like 75 CA keys in addition to the one key I added.  Clearly, this isn't going to keep anyone from sending us untrusted code.

Is there a way to tell the SSL system to only use a single certificate?  Should I be using a completely different approach?

Update:
Changing the cacerts file isn't really an option here.  The JVM should continue to function normally for other applications using it.  Is there a way, at runtime, to elect not to load that file? I'm looking at the TrustManager and KeyManager classes but I don't really understand how to use them.

Comment: Hi, I know this question is relatively old but I have a couple of questions if anyone would be kind enough to answer! Firstly, if I add these lines to my application, will they only affect my application or are they global. Secondly, does anybody know if it is possible to have a keystore folder actually inside the JAR? And finally, what actually needs to be inside the keystore folder? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` system property to point to a keystore with your one certificate in it. The keystore is for your authentication credentials, not your peer's.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The very question is wrong here. A certificate is only a proof of identity. You don't authorize certificates, you authorize identities. What if the same client comes up with a new certificate?

The correct answer is to install a `HandshakeCompletedListener` that checks the peer identity. The truststore is only there for authentication, i.e. is that person who they said they were. What you are doing is authorization, which is a different thing completely. You shouldn't use the truststore (or any PKI mechanism) for authorization.

Comment: This is for an application distributed with single trusted CA certificate.  We're issuing certificates to control which servers will be trusted by the client program.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. A certificate isn't an identity, it is a proof of identity. An identity can have multiple certificates. Treating the certificate as an identity is a grade A category mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You also have the global keystore installed with the JRE, which is where all the CA's are stored.  Try to rename it and see what happens.

Comment: Renaming the cacerts file works but I can't go breaking the user's SSL libraries just for my app.

Answer (score 0):

You still "see" the CA certificates of the system-wide JRE `cacerts` file located in `java.home/jre/lib/security`, which is normal.

Now, quoting the [keytool documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html#cacerts) about this file:

> **IMPORTANT: Verify Your cacerts File**
>   Since you trust the CAs in
>   the `cacerts` file as entities for
>   signing and issuing certificates to
>   other entities, you must manage the
>   `cacerts` file carefully. The `cacerts`
>   file should contain only certificates
>   of the CAs you trust. It is your
>   responsibility to verify the trusted
>   root CA certificates bundled in the
>   `cacerts` file and make your own trust
>   decisions. To remove an untrusted CA
>   certificate from the `cacerts` file, use
>   the delete option of the `keytool`
>   command. You can find the `cacerts` file
>   in the JRE installation directory.
>   Contact your system administrator if
>   you do not have permission to edit
>   this file.

In your case, it might be easier to entirely replace the `cacerts` with your own key store instead of removing all 75 entries if this is really what you want. If not, then you should use a different approach indeed (why don't you just restrict or hard code the list of authorized servers?).